# MS-Access WHERE filter syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter From Date:] Text ( 255 ), [Enter To Date:] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM Count([Staff Programs].ID) AS CountofProgram
SELECT [Staff Programs].program_name
FROM [Staff Programs]
WHERE ((([Staff Programs].is_noshow)=No) AND (([Staff Programs].actual_date) Between [Enter From date:] And And [Enter To Date:]))
GROUP BY [Staff Programs].program_name
PIVOT [Staff Programs].staff_name;
```

I need to add one thing to the `WHERE` clause.

I have a column in the table called "Event Name"> I would like to skip any of the rows where this value is one of: 'Phone Contact', 'Cinician Travel', 'Reporting' or 'Collateral Contact'.

I have been unable to locate the syntax for this.

Comment: Add another `AND` clause to your `WHERE`?

Comment: Also check this part: `Between [Enter From date:] And And [Enter To Date:]`, remove one `AND`

Comment: Good to finally see a parameterized query in MS Access!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
AND ([Event Name] NOT IN ('Phone Contact', 'Cinician Travel', 'Reporting', 'Collateral Contact'))
```

I think it's easy to understand, more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/in-operator-d5a10cdc-cdb2-4854-be22-7abdeb5a3236)